# Access information throughout files in React Native app

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

Currently, I have an app for an specific event and I have a *config.js* inside my project that has some information that never change, like primary color, default language and name of the event. I export these const from the config file like this:

```
export const defaultLanguage = 'en';
export const templatePrimary = '#692728';
export const eventName = 'presentation';
```

and I use them throughout the app, importing them in other files whenever necessary (the eventName for example is imported in 28 different files).

**But from now on, I want my app to be multi event** and I want these information to change according to the event the user selects.

So from now on when the app is opened I would get from Firebase a list of events and the user would select one of them and each event would have name, primary color and default language and, according to the selection, the config file that I mentioned above would change.

My question: is it possible to achieve this with Redux? Or even if it is possible, is it recommended?

I'm trying to think of something that could properly replace the config file approach above without me having to change all the files that have to use these info.

In addition, what would be the best approach?

Comment: I would use redux with redux-thunk. Especially if list of events can change when app is working. I don't know whether you can do this not touching your 28 files

Comment: thanks @kenodek I'll look for more info on redux-thunk. After a while I'm starting to get use to the idea of having to go through my entire project to make this change happen